# Error JsonTextReader.ReadAsString() C# using json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I am a new user of Json.net and I am stuck because of an error message.
I want to read a json file thanks to JsonTextReader using json.net
My json file is a list of my class Person with some attributes looks like that:
http://pastebin.com/DbSDVt2K
When reading with the StreamReader (or TextReader) I have no problem.
What i want is to have the same result with an output of type JsonTextReader.

Here is my piece of code to help you understand:
http://pastebin.com/iwF3xuUp

My error is with: myString = reader.ReadAsString();
" Additional information: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."

I have been looking for hours to have more info but I found nothing that could help me.

If any of you can help me understand this error and find a solution.

Here is a extract of my tr file content:

```
[
    {
        "FirstName": "X",
        "LastName": "Y",
        "Hobbies": "Cuisine",
        "Age": 35,
        "Country": "France",
        "Address": "unknown",
        "Phone": "unknown",
        "Gender": "male"
    },
    {
        "FirstName": "W",
        "LastName": "Z",
        "Hobbies": "Jouer",
        "Age": 43,
        "Country": "France",
        "Address": "unknown",
        "Phone": "unknown",
        "Gender": "male"
    },
    ...
```

Comment: Not sure I understand - are you able to de/serialize your data, just not able to return text of type JsonTextReader?

Comment: @jacoblam Sorry for not being clear.
I have a function:
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
I am trying to obtain a JsonTextReader to call it in my function.
I was just wondering my JsonTextReader's value in order to see if everything went good. (because I am a beginner with json.net

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have just to remove this line from your code: `string myString = reader.ReadAsString();` The Json Serializer tries to read a string there, but recognizes that it is an Array which you're trying to read.

```
TextReader tr = File.OpenText(path);
List<Person> myPersonList = new List<Person>();
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(tr);
JsonSerializer jseri = new JsonSerializer();

object parsedData = jseri.Deserialize(reader);
```

and if you want to have it directly to your correct type you can also use the generic Deserialze instead of Deserialize.

than you can specifiy the deserialization as:

```
List<Person> parsedData = jseri.Deserialize<List<Person>>(reader);
```

**Edit for the comment:**

If you want to reuse a JsonReader you can create a reader from a JObject:

```
JObject o = new JObject
{
    { "Cpu", "Intel" },
    { "Memory", 32 },
    {
        "Drives", new JArray
        {
            "DVD",
            "SSD"
        }
    }
};

JsonReader reader = o.CreateReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.Write(reader.TokenType);
    if (reader.Value != null)
        Console.Write(" - " + reader.Value);

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Example comes from [Using JToken.CreateReader](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CreateReader.htm) from the Newtonsoft Help Page

Comment: Thanks for answering!

I have another question about the use of json.net. If I am doing a:
JObject resultMessage = JObject.Load(reader);
with the same reader, I also have an error " Additional information: Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: EndArray. Path '', line 1, position 8811."

That's why I wanted to test with string myString. To see the content of my JsonTextReader.
Do you think that this second error I have is because: the Json Serializer tries to read a string but recognizes an Array (as you said). If yes, is there a way to Load(reader)?

Comment: See my edit please, but that will also only read a Json Object not an Array of Objects!

Comment: I am gonna have a look on the website you sent me. Thanks again for your precise answers.

Answer (score 0):

Simply read the file with a regular TextReader, then Deserialize using JsonConvert.

```
System.IO.TextReader textReader = System.IO.File.OpenText(path);
string all = textReader.ReadToEnd();
m_Elements = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyType>(all);
```